# ArrayList not being populated

Tags: java, arraylist

I am making a Robot Maze where the robot finds the target without crashing into walls.

My code compiles fine however:

- At `deadends` the robot seems to try to advance in the direction it's facing and subsequently crashes into walls a lot.
- At `corridors`, the `ArrayList` is empty and I don't know why.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: When you call `corridor`, you haven't called `passageExits` as far as I can tell - so that explains that one...

Comment: Additionally, in both your `passageExits` and `nonWallExits` methods, you're *unconditionally* adding directions to your list - only the counter increment is part of the `if` statement. You need braces around the body: `if (condition) { statement1; statement2; }`

Comment: You need to call passageExists and noWallExists methods to populate the two arraylists, before calling your deadend and corridor methods.

Comment: @Prateek How would I do that? `return passageExits(robot).passageDirections.get(0);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your passageExists method returns the number of passages that exist, as an integer.
So you first need to check if the number of passages that exists are >1, only then you get something from the arrayList.

That is to say, you so something like this:

```
if(passageExists(robot) > 0)
   passageDirections.get(0);
```

And same is the case with walls.

Comment: But it needs a return statement?

Comment: Ya, so what you do is in your corridor function you say if(passageExists(robot) > 0) return passageDirections.get(0). Something like this. In fact I'd suggest don't make these two arraylists global

Comment: originally they weren't global. They were in the corresponding method. E.g. `passageDirections` `ArrayList` was in the `passageExits` method. However, it wasn't compiling :(. I have done the following: `if (passageExits(robot) == 1) return passageDirections.get(0);` however, when compiling it says it is missing a `return` statement :(

Comment: Yes so you should continue with the same, and return the arrayList from passageExists method, rather than the number of passages, and in corridor, add logic to check if the number of passages that exist are greater than 0, return the first passage.

Comment: if I return the arrayLists then I would have to change most of my code where I call the number of passageExits

Comment: I think making that effort is worth it to avoid the number of issues you would encounter by keeping these global.

Comment: Thing is, I can't return the ArrayList because it's expecting an int to be returned.

Comment: The return type is very much in your control :)